# Global field in method Java

Tags: java

Here is my code:

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
 {
 JButton source = (JButton)e.getSource();
 if(source == buttonShop)
 {  
 try
 {
 Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "xxx", "xxx");
 Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();               
 ResultSet myRs1 = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from shop");   

 while(myRs1.next())
 {
 shop += myRs1.getString("ID_SHOP")+" "+myRs1.getString("NAME")+" "+myRs1.getString("ADRESS")+" "+myRs1.getString("PHONE")+"\n";
 }      
 }catch(Exception exc){
 exc.printStackTrace();
 }; 
 notifyObserver1();
 shop = "";
 }
 else if(source == buttonEmployee)
 {
 try
 {
 Connection myConn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false", "xxx", "xxx");
 Statement myStmt = myConn.createStatement();               
 ResultSet myRs2 = myStmt.executeQuery("select * from employee");   

 while(myRs2.next())
 {
 employee += myRs2.getString("ID_EMPLOYEE")+" "+myRs2.getString("ID_SHOP")+" "+myRs2.getString("NAME")+" "+myRs2.getString("SURNAME")+"\n";
 }      
 }catch(Exception exc){
 exc.printStackTrace();
 }; 
 notifyObserver2();
 employee = "";
 }
 }
```

This is a database app. I don't want to copy-paste every Connection myConn =... and Statement myStmt =... fragment to all button sources. How to make it 'global' to be visible out of actionPerformed method?

Comment: This is why java has methods

Comment: Read about a concept called connection pool.

Comment: @MichaelGantman Yeah, indeed a very good suggestion.

Comment: Spring JDBC is also really useful.

Comment: You really should learn about the benefits of indenting your code - it makes it *so much* easier to read (both for you and others).

Answer (score 0):

First You should have a Db Utility say 'DBUtil' class with at least a getConnection method.
This getConnection should create a connection or return it from pool depending upon your implementation.

```
DBUtil Class:
static Connection getConnection()
```

After that create two helper methods to handle both of the scenarios, something like:

```
getEmployeeDetails(){}
getShopDetails(){}
```

Inside these methods you should ideally use:

```
try(Connection conn = DBUtil.getConnection();
    PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement("Your Qry");
    ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery()){

   // Do Something

}
```

Some good points:

1. Use PreparedStatements
2. Use Try with Resource to prevent resource leaks or handle it manually
3. As a good practice, create, initialize and close the resource within a single method. You should not pass the resources to other methods for processing, this type of design can lead to major leak issues.

You can also make one generalized method, pass the query string to that, do some conditional processing and then return the final result to caller. This generalized method will handle db communication.

Comment: Does this answer your question @Mariachi ??